# How to use loop over two columns and print first one only if second column contains specific string

Tags: bash, awk

This is the sample file:

```
someText here some other columns (exist but I don't intend to read them)
anotherText there some other columns (exist but I don't intend to read them)
YouAreGood here some other columns (exist but I don't intend to read them)
HeIsNormal there some other columns (exist but I don't intend to read them)
```

I want to check if the second column is `here`, then do something.

This is my attempt, in which I'm not sure how to properly:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

awk '{print $2}' sample | while read -r line
do
    if [ "$line" == 'here' ]
    then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```

Expected output in a second file:

```
someText
YouAreGood
```

I thought about using `awk '{print $2}' sample`, or `if [ "$line '{print $2}'" == 'here' ]`, but it will execute `else` block always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this `awk` should work for you:

```bash
awk '$2 == "here" {print $1}' file

someText
YouAreGood
```

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution is going to be more efficient but if you really need to do this in `bash` ...

Let `read` split (on whitespace) each line for us:

```
while read -r word1 word2 rest_of_line
do
    if [[ "${word2}" == 'here' ]]
    then
        echo "${word1}"
    fi
done < sample
```

This generates:

```
someText
YouAreGood
```

---

If you need to capture/use the entire line while also working with the first 2 (whitespace-delimited) words ...

We can break the `while/read` into two separate operations:

```
while read -r line
do
    read -r word1 word2 rest_of_line <<< "${line}"

    echo "########### ${line}"

    if [[ "${word2}" == 'here' ]]
    then
        echo "${word1}"
    fi
done < sample
```

This generates:

```
########### someText here some other columns (exist but I don't intend to read them)
someText
########### anotherText there some other columns (exist but I don't intend to read them)
########### YouAreGood here some other columns (exist but I don't intend to read them)
YouAreGood
########### HeIsNormal there some other columns (exist but I don't intend to read them)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mawk 'NF = "here" == $2'
```

---

```
someText
YouAreGood
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '^\S+\s+(?=\bhere\b)' file
```

Perl:

```
perl -lnE 'say $1 if /^(\S+)\s+(?=\bhere\b)/' file
```

Or

```
perl -lanE 'say $F[0] if $F[1]=~/\bhere\b/' file
```

Ruby:

```
ruby -lane 'puts $F[0] if $F[1][/\bhere\b/]' file
```

sed:

```
sed -nE 's/^([^[:space:]]{1,})[[:space:]]here[[:space:]].*/\1/p' file
```

Any prints:

```
someText 
YouAreGood
```